# Creating a Multi-column sort that also adds a line between different items

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So I've got a start on the code to sort a list of materials where I can enter the materials how I want (seen here) [image]
and then it will sort to the correct way as seen below.

Where I've got the "Let the Magic Happen v2" button to automatically sort the list to the way I want it, but I want to then add a new line (that is also still formatted with the boxes and formulas) like this: [image]

This is my current code, but I'm stuck on how to add a "blank" line in between the different materials/sizes:

```
Private Sub Let_The_Magic_Happen_v2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("J35:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "HRT,LASER,DELRIN,HDPE,8#XLPE", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L35:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("M35:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("N35:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("O35:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A35:W" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").END(xlUp).Row)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I appreciate any help that you can provide, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a good solution to my problem as seen by the code below:
Essentially what I do is I go through the Material type column and check if there is anything in that row and the next row, if there is something, I check to see if they are equal to each other and increment my counter. If they aren't equal, then I know that they must be different materials and thus, I add a space between them. I also have a check in here that makes sure that there is not already a space between the two materials, so that it doesn't duplicate more unneeded spaces.

```
' Version Number: v2.1.1

Private Sub Let_The_Magic_Happen_v2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Sorts the worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("J35:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "HRT,HRTRND,HRA,HRCNL,HRRND,HRFLT,HRSHT,CFRND,CFFLT,ALT,ALTRND,ALA,ALCNL,ALRND,ALFLT,SSRND,SSA,SSFLT,SSSHT,LASER,DELRIN,NYLON,HDPE,UMHW,8#XLPE,MISC", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L35:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("M35:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("N35:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("O35:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A35:W" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'Removes the extra rows at the end of the cut sheet, as they are not needed (but leave two extra rows at the bottom for looks)
Dim Lastrow1 As Long
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Rng = "J35:J" & Lastrow
Lastrow1 = Lastrow - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range(Rng))
Dim EndOfCut As Range
    With Range("U1:U32000")
        Set EndOfCut = .Find(What:="CUT LIST SUBTOTAL", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not EndOfCut Is Nothing Then
            Cell_Add = Split(EndOfCut.Address, "$")
            ThisRow = Cell_Add(1)
            ThisCol = Cell_Add(2)
            If ((ThisCol - 1) - (Lastrow1 + 1)) > 3 Then
                Rows((Lastrow1 + 3) & ":" & (ThisCol - 1)).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Else
            msgboxresponse = MsgBox("CUT LIST SUBTOTAL not found")
        End If
    End With

'Scrolls through the list and inserts a line between different materials
With Range("J35").Select
    Dim counter As long
    counter = 35
    mtlname = "a"
    mtlname2 = "a"
    Dim EndCount As long
    EndCount = Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Do While counter < EndCount
    softEnd0:
    mtlname = "a"
    mtlname2 = "a"
    Do While (mtlname = mtlname2)
        If counter >= EndCount Then 
            GoTo hardEnd0
        Else
            mtlname = Cells(counter, 10)
            counter = counter + 1
            mtlname2 = Cells(counter, 10)
        End If
    Loop
    With Sheets("Quote_and_Cut")
        If mtlname2 = "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            GoTo softEnd0
        Else
            .Range(.Cells(counter, 1), .Cells(counter, 23)).Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
            counter = counter + 1
            EndCount = EndCount + 1
        End If
    End With
hardEnd0:
Loop


'Scrolls through the list and inserts a line between different DIM1
With Range("L35").Select
    counter = 35
    dim1name = "0"
    dim1name2 = "0"
    EndCount = Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Do While counter < EndCount
    softEnd1:
    dim1name = "0"
    dim1name2 = "0"
    Do While (dim1name = dim1name2)
        If counter >= EndCount Then 
            GoTo hardEnd1
        Else
            dim1name = Cells(counter, 12)
            counter = counter + 1
            dim1name2 = Cells(counter, 12)
        End If
    Loop
    With Sheets("Quote_and_Cut")
        If Cells(counter, 10) = "" Or Cells(counter -1, 10) = "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            GoTo softEnd1
        Else
            .Range(.Cells(counter, 1), .Cells(counter, 23)).Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
            counter = counter + 1
            EndCount = EndCount + 1
        End If
    End With
Loop
hardEnd1:  
End With

'Scrolls through the list and inserts a line between different DIM2
With Range("M35").Select
    counter = 35
    dim2name = "0"
    dim2name2 = "0"
    EndCount = Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Do While counter < EndCount
    softEnd2:
    dim2name = "0"
    dim2name2 = "0"
    Do While (dim2name = dim2name2)
        If counter >= EndCount Then 
            GoTo hardEnd2
        Else
            dim2name = Cells(counter, 13)
            counter = counter + 1
            dim2name2 = Cells(counter, 13)
        End If
    Loop
    With Sheets("Quote_and_Cut")
        If Cells(counter, 10) = "" Or Cells(counter -1, 10) = "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            GoTo softEnd2
        Else
            .Range(.Cells(counter, 1), .Cells(counter, 23)).Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
            counter = counter + 1
            EndCount = EndCount + 1
        End If
    End With
Loop
hardEnd2:  
End With

'Scrolls through the list and inserts a line between different DIM3
With Range("N35").Select
    counter = 35
    dim3name = "0"
    dim3name2 = "0"
    EndCount = Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Do While counter < EndCount
    softEnd3:
    dim3name = "0"
    dim3name2 = "0"
    Do While (dim3name = dim3name2)
        If counter >= EndCount Then 
            GoTo hardEnd3
        Else
            dim3name = Cells(counter, 14)
            counter = counter + 1
            dim3name2 = Cells(counter, 14)
        End If
    Loop
    With Sheets("Quote_and_Cut")
        If Cells(counter, 10) = "" Or Cells(counter -1, 10) = "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            GoTo softEnd3
        Else
            .Range(.Cells(counter, 1), .Cells(counter, 23)).Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
            counter = counter + 1
            EndCount = EndCount + 1
        End If
    End With
Loop
hardEnd3:  
End With

'Fixes the Cut List Subtotal SUM, because Excel tries to change it during sort
Dim ThisPos As Range
    With Range("U1:U32000")
        Set ThisPos = .Find(What:="CUT LIST SUBTOTAL", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not ThisPos Is Nothing Then
            Cell_Add = Split(ThisPos.Address, "$")
            ThisRow = Cell_Add(1)
            ThisCol = Cell_Add(2)
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_and_Cut").Range("W" & ThisCol).Value = "=SUM(W35:W" & (ThisCol - 1) & ")"
        Else
            msgboxresponse = MsgBox("CUT LIST SUBTOTAL not found")
        End If
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @Toto I made an attempt to elaborate on what my code does. Hopefully it's not as useless now? Let me know.